# How to cut text from a file and write the changes to the same file?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing

I have a file like:

```
171023 03014426 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123, pc=546, call=0,
171023 03110749 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123, pc=546, call=0,
```

I need to keep the lines with timestamp, ie `171023 03014426 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX` and keep `error code: 123` from the other lines, ie from start of line until the comma, and write the changes to the same file.

Output:

```
171023 03014426 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123
171023 03110749 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123
```

How can I do that?

Comment: are u using vim. switch to visual mode v or ctrl+v select the error to , then press d and append to top line at end with A then p. Or can just remove the new line at end of time stamp. or use sed externally on this file to remove the new line character for in place replacement

Comment: I need shell script command to do the same

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your question, you want this

```
171023 03014426 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123, pc=546, call=0,
171023 03110749 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123, pc=546, call=0,
```

to become this:

```
171023 03014426 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123
171023 03110749 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123
```

There are many ways to do this, so choose method that you want/like/prefer.

## sed

```
$ sed 's/\(error code:[[:blank:]][[:digit:]]*\),.*/\1/' input.txt                                     
171023 03014426 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123
171023 03110749 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123
```

If you want to make changes to original file `input.txt`, use `sed -i` instead of just `sed`

## awk

```
$ awk -F ',' '/^error code/{$0=$1};1' input.txt                                                       
171023 03014426 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123
171023 03110749 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123
```

This approach makes comma to be treated as column ( in awk-speak "field" ) separator, so here we basically find line that starts with `error code` text and replace original line with only column `$1`, which in your case happens to be everything before comma, i.e. `error code: 123`.

`awk` cannot do in-text editing ( most versions ), like `sed -i` but you can always output things to new file, and replace old file with new like:

```
awk -F ',' '/^error code/{$0=$1};1' input.txt > new_data.txt && mv new_data.txt input.txt
```

## pure bash

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# make temp file for writing stuff
temp=$(mktemp)

# read input file, make necessary changes, write to temp file
while IFS= read -r line;
do
    case $line in
        "error code:"*) printf "%s\n" "${line%%,*}" >> "$temp";;
        *) printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "$temp";;
    esac
done < "$1"
mv  "$temp" "$1"
```

Test run:

```
$ # before 
$ cat input.txt                                                                                       
171023 03014426 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123, pc=546, call=0,
171023 03110749 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123, pc=546, call=0,
$ # after
$ ./edit_error_codes.sh input.txt                                                                     
$ cat input.txt
171023 03014426 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123
171023 03110749 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123
```

Comment: Instead of `IFS= read`, using `IFS=, read -r line extra` might get you the part before the comma for free.

Comment: @muru yeah, I was considering that one as well; it's probably better that way

Comment: Why not a simple `cut -d"," -f1`?

Comment: @Ziazis sure, can work well enough.

Answer (score 3):

If the lines you don't want to touch have no commas, and you always want only to delete the first comma and everything after it, you can use a very simple expression

```
$ sed 's/,.*//' file
171023 03014426 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123
171023 03110749 1234 XXXX XXXXXXXX
error code: 123
```

- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*` any number of any characters

To edit the file in place, use `sed`'s in-place option, which is `-i`. If a suffix for the backup file is added after `-i`, it automatically writes a backup of the original file with that extension in the same directory, for example

```
sed -i 's/,.*//' file
```

overwrites `file` with the modified stream, but

```
sed -i.orig 's/,.*//' file
```

writes the modified stream to `file` and writes a new file `file.orig` with the original contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `cut` command to do what you want.

```
cut -d"," -f1 input.txt
```

Write it back to the same file.

```
cut -d"," -f1 input.txt | tee input.txt
```